# Yii checkAccess method return false in login request

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I wrote following code to assign role to user in authentication method

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

if(!$auth->isAssigned($user->type,$user->id))
{
    if($auth->assign($user->type,$user->id))
    {
            Yii::app()->authManager->save();    
            var_dump(Yii::app()->authManager->getRoles($user->id));
            var_dump(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($user->type));
    }
}
```

The above code return

```
array(1) { 'USER' => class CAuthItem#77 (8) { private $_auth => class CPhpAuthManager#76 (10) { public $authFile => string(25) "protected/config/auth.php" private $_items => array(6) { ... } private $_children => array(2) { ... } private $_assignments => array(2) { ... } public $showErrors => bool(false) public $defaultRoles => array(0) { ... } public $behaviors => array(0) { ... } private $_initialized => bool(true) private $_e => NULL private $_m => NULL } private $_type => int(2) private $_name => string(4) "USER" private $_description => string(14) "User Role Type" private $_bizRule => string(0) "" private $_data => string(0) "" private $_e => NULL private $_m => NULL } }

bool(false)
```

but if I use `checkAccess` in next request it will return true.something like `save` method works asynchronously and doesn't save rules as it called.

This is my config for auth:

```
            'authManager'=>array(
                'class'     =>  'CPhpAuthManager',
                'authFile'  =>  'protected/config/auth.php',
            ),
```

I follow [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/65/how-to-setup-rbac-with-a-php-file/)

Answer (score 0):

Try without caching

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($user->type, array(), false);
```

Comment: returns same result as I posted

Comment: Try `Yii::app()->authManager->load();` after save and you could also call checkAccess directly `Yii::app()->authManager->checkAccess($user->type,$user->id);`. But this will not guarantee success because save uses file_put_contents() function which is not atomic. This means you can read file while the other process is saving it. The best thing would be to use CDbAuthManager instead and to put roles in the database which is inherently optimized for concurrency.